# Firebase Auth blocking layout inflation?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem inmplementing Firebase Authentication on my Android app.
I'm following instructions from Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3 (Tools -> Firebase -> Authentication -> Set up Firebase Authentication).

Here's `my onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }

        }
    };
    Log.d(TAG, mAuth.toString());

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    final EditText emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
    final EditText passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
    Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = emailField.getText().toString();
            String password = passwordField.getText().toString();

            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete: " + task.isSuccessful());

                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    });


}
```

So, here's a problem: the activity won't show up. I mean it runs, but it won't show up on the screen. The logs suggest, that it runs, and the `onAuthStateChanged()` method is called (Log shows: `D/RegisterActivity: onAuthStateChanged:signed_out`) but the layout doesn't inflate.

I think the culprit is this line: 
`mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);`, because as I comment out this single line, the layout shows up. Any ideas why this could prevent layout from starting up?

This is the log after starting up this activity:

```
06-14 22:37:42.711 16802-16802/com.example.jedrzej.sortify V/FA: onActivityCreated
06-14 22:37:42.718 16802-16802/com.example.jedrzej.sortify D/RegisterActivity: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzadg@16346d13
06-14 22:37:42.721 16802-16859/com.example.jedrzej.sortify V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 5573595
06-14 22:37:42.758 16802-16867/com.example.jedrzej.sortify W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-14 22:37:42.758 16802-16867/com.example.jedrzej.sortify W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa1d09280, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-14 22:37:42.812 16802-16802/com.example.jedrzej.sortify D/RegisterActivity: onAuthStateChanged:signed_out
06-14 22:37:42.942 16802-16859/com.example.jedrzej.sortify V/FA: Activity paused, time: 5573818
06-14 22:37:43.013 16802-16859/com.example.jedrzej.sortify V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 5573889
06-14 22:37:45.584 16802-16859/com.example.jedrzej.sortify V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
06-14 22:37:50.342 16802-16847/com.example.jedrzej.sortify E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.jedrzej.sortify-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.jedrzej.sortify-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```